# Is there a way to configure DNS records to ultimately resolve a domain (`example.com`) to a subdomain (`www.example.com`)?

Tags: domain-name-system, namecheap, dns-record

Currently, I have an AWS S3 Bucket named `www.example.com` setup to host static files and a CNAME record with host `www` and target `www.example.com.s3-website-some-region.amazonaws.com`.

I would like to set up a DNS record to ultimately resolve the base domain `example.com` to subdomain `www.example.com`.

I have tried the following DNS record set ups while also having the aforementioned CNAME record ( I APOLOGIZE FOR THE UNDERSCORES, BUT STACK WAS CALLING MY POST SPAM BECAUSE I HAD TOO MANY URLS/DOMAINS. PLEASE REPLACE THE UNDERSCORES BELOW WITH PERIODS ):

1. ALIAS Record with Host `@` and target `www_example_com` which resulted in `HTTP ERROR 404`.
2. URL Redirect Record with Host `@` and destination url `http://www_example_com/` which resulted in `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`.
3. CNAME Record HOST `@` with target `www_example_com` which resulted in name resolution, but a response from AWS that there is no such bucket ( which makes sense ).

The question from the title "Is there a way to configure DNS records to ultimately resolve a domain (`example.com`) to a subdomain (`www.example.com`)?" has a stipulation that the HOST HTTP HEADER is `www.example.com` ( which is what i believe to be the reason why the CNAME record test from above didn't work ).

Why does the ALIAS record result in an HTTP ERROR 404.

Why does the URL Redirect record result in DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error. I setup a URL Redirect record for other subdomains to redirect to the `www` sub domain. However,  the URL Redirect from the base domain does not seem to work. The browser does not redirect `example.com` to `http://www.example.com`.

Is there a reason why I can't have a URL redirect record from a base domain to a url?

[I understand that I can setup a redirect directly on AWS ( which is more than likely what I'll be doing )](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-configure-redirect)

[example domain records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US0wW.png)

Comment: "Is there a way to configure DNS records to ultimately resolve a domain (example.com) to a subdomain (www.example.com)?" Soon yes, or already at certain providers but not all clients will use them: look at new DNS HTTPS/SVCB records. They exist exactly to offer the "CNAME at apex" feature (but other things too). As for the rest, if you want specific help you need to give the real names. Or do yourself an online test using the very good DNSViz utility.

Comment: Awesome! Do you have a link to a site where I can read more about this?

Comment: Start maybe with https://www.domaintools.com/resources/blog/the-use-cases-and-benefits-of-svcb-and-https-dns-record-types or https://blog.cloudflare.com/speeding-up-https-and-http-3-negotiation-with-dns/ ; Support is slowly being added to Chrome, Firefox, Safari...

Answer (score 1):

sorry for my english, I'm french ;)  You can't create a CNAME record for the top node of a DNS namespace like "example.com", but only for subdomains like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), myserver.example.com, etc.

Note also if you create a CNAME record for a subdomain, you cannot create any other records for that subdomain anymore. Example: if you create a CNAME for myserver.example.com, you cannot create any other records for which the value of the Name field is myserver.example.com.

Hope that will helps you.